# The correct grammar to express "this part was forgot to be modified"?

Tags: grammar

I would like to express

We are having a problem because

"this part was forgot to be modified" or 
  "this part was missed to be modified"?

Do those two sentences make sense?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Only a person can forget something. Modification of this part was forgotten [by the team, by the worker, by whomever]. X [the team] forgot to modify this part. The team missed modifying this part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those two sentences do not make much sense.

A better phrase would be: "We forgot to modify this part."

Or: "This part was missed during modification."